# Why do ping to internet don't work?

Tags: networking, routing, ping

**Internet Router** IP 192.168.5.1; Internet-IP

**Box1** IP 192.168.1.240; 192.168.5.240, 192.168.200.240

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.5.1     0.0.0.0         UG    3      0        0 enp7s0f1
127.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp7s0f0
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     3      0        0 enp7s0f1
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp7s0f0
```

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward = 1
Firewall stopped and rules cleared

**Box2** IP 192.168.200.15; 192.168.1.15

```
Kernel IP Routentabelle
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.200.240 0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp3s0
127.0.0.0       127.0.0.1       255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 lo
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp2s0
192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp3s0
```

(only for Information: 192.168.1.1 is another Router)

***ping Box1:* fine**

> PING 192.168.200.240 (192.168.200.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.200.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.067 ms
>   --- 192.168.200.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.067/0.067/0.067/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.200.15 (192.168.200.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.200.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.098 ms
>   --- 192.168.200.15 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.098/0.098/0.098/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.1.240 (192.168.1.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
>   --- 192.168.1.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.063/0.063/0.063/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.329 ms
>   --- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.329/0.329/0.329/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.5.240 (192.168.5.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.5.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.044 ms
>   --- 192.168.5.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.044/0.044/0.044/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.5.1 (192.168.5.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.5.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.719 ms
>   --- 192.168.5.1 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.719/0.719/0.719/0.000 ms
>
> PING www.heise.de (193.99.144.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from www.heise.de (193.99.144.85): icmp_seq=1 ttl=248 time=17.0 ms
>   --- www.heise.de ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 17.068/17.068/17.068/0.000 ms

***ping Box2:* Don't work as i want to**

> PING 192.168.200.15 (192.168.200.15) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.200.15: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.041 ms
>   --- 192.168.200.15 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.041/0.041/0.041/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.200.240 (192.168.200.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.200.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.245 ms
>   --- 192.168.200.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.245/0.245/0.245/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.1.240 (192.168.1.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.285 ms
>   --- 192.168.1.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.285/0.285/0.285/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.529 ms
>   --- 192.168.1.1 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.529/0.529/0.529/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.5.240 (192.168.5.240) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   64 bytes from 192.168.5.240: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.171 ms
>   --- 192.168.5.240 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
>   rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.171/0.171/0.171/0.000 ms
>
> PING 192.168.5.1 (192.168.5.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   --- 192.168.5.1 ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
>
> PING www.heise.de (193.99.144.85) 56(84) bytes of data.
>   --- www.heise.de ping statistics ---
>   1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

**Question:** Why can't i ping from 192.168.200.15 (Box2) to IP 192.168.5.1 and 193.99.144.85? Any Idea/Solution to get it work?

Answer (score 1):

Your router `192.168.5.1` doesn't know where is the network `192.168.200.0/24`. That's why you need add static route `network 192.168.200.0/24 via 192.168.5.240` on the router. Also check NAT rules on the router and add network `192.168.200.0/24` there.